# Use progressBar of R shiny within a function

Tags: r, shiny

Using progressbar in R shiny is quite straightforward when it comes within the server function :

```
library(shiny)
source(myFunctions.R)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

withProgress(message = 'Chargement des données', value = 0, {
incProgress(0.5)
function1()
incProgress(0.6)
function2()
incProgress(0.7)
function3()
incProgress(0.8)
})
})
```

But what if I want to have them inside a function, for instance:

```
Allfunction <- function(){
withProgress(message = 'Chargement des données', value = 0, {
incProgress(0.5)
function1()
incProgress(0.6)
function2()
incProgress(0.7)
function3()
incProgress(0.8)
})
}
```

and hence

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
Allfunction()
})
```

Then I get

```
Warning: Error in withProgress: 'session' is not a ShinySession object.
```

and adding a session argument to the function, as advertised on a google forum did'nt do it.

Comment: Can you post a runnable, reproducible example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `withProgress()` inside a function should not be a problem. Here is a working example. Note by the way that `incProgress` works cumulative, i.e. if you want to go from `0.5` to `0.6`, you only have to add `0.1` as argument in the function.

Hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  actionButton('click','click me!')

))

Allfunction <- function(){
  withProgress(message = 'Chargement des données', value = 0, {
    incProgress(0.5)
    function1()
    incProgress(0.1)
    function2()
    incProgress(0.1)
    function3()
    incProgress(0.1)
  })
}

function1 <- function(){Sys.sleep(1)}
function2 <- function1
function3 <- function1

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$click, {
    Allfunction()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```